# Dataset is empty

Tags: visual-studio, ms-access

I have a problem, I'm working on a school project with Visual Basic and I can't manage to fill a dataset with a LIKE query.

I'm using Access in order to manage the database and the query is:

```
SELECT * FROM VistaProductos WHERE Nombre LIKE "*ta*"
```

In Access this query is working fine but when I use it on Visual Basic the OleDbDataAdapter fills my DataSet with 0 rows.

Here is the code:

```
Dim adaptador As New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM VistaProductos WHERE " & campo & " LIKE ""*" & valor & "*""", conexion)
adaptador.Fill(dataset, tabla)
Return dataset
```

campo and valor are variables who have the same data as in the Access example, and I tried by writing them literally too.

The connection to the database is working fine as the other querys work perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ADO.NET uses the standard % character as wildcard in LIKE expressions.

But your first problem to solve is removing the string concatenations when you build sql queries. You cannot trust your user on this point. If you leave in that way you user can write anything and you risk to pass malicious commands to your database engine. You should always use parameters in these contexts

In your code is present also a field name as a variable part of the query.
This cannot be parameterized, so the only sensible solution is to present your user with a list of field names to choose from

```
Dim cmdText = "SELECT * FROM VistaProductos WHERE " & campo & " LIKE @valor"
Dim adaptador As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmdText, conexion)
adaptador.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@valor", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = "%" & valor & "%"
adaptador.Fill(dataset, tabla)
Return dataset
```

Comment: Finally! Thank you, I solved it with the % character. And thank you much for those tips, I will definitely use them!